# JavaScript: sorting string according to numbers it contains

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort a string which contains a single number from 1-9. For e.g. string is "Ho2w are1 y3ou" then resulting string should be **"are1 Ho2w y3ou"**. For that, I have used for...of loop to iterate over a string and used split to convert it into an array of string and then used sort method but I am not getting an output. Can anyone suggest what's wrong in my program?

code ::

```
function order(words){
let result = "";
for (let value of words) {
  result += value;
}

let splited = result.split(" ");
  if(words === ""){
    return "";
  }
  return splited.sort((a,b) => a - b);

}

order("Ho2w are1 y3ou");
```

Comment: `result` is not defined anywhere?

Comment: Defined it in program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to somehow find the number in the word that you want to use to sort. One way to do this is with [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and a regular expression:

```js
let str =  "Ho2w are1 y3ou"

let sorted = 
str.split(' ')
.sort((a,b) => a.match(/\d+/)[0] -  b.match(/\d+/)[0]) // sort based on first number found
.join(' ')

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: Then no need to use for...of loop ?

Comment: No need for the `for` loop. `split()` makes and array. `sort()` sorts it, and `join()` puts it back together as a string.

Comment: Why `match`? the `replace` function is a better suit for this question.

Comment: @Ele, `match` was the first things that came to mind. Why is replace better?

Comment: ps. @Ele. At least on Chrome and Safari, Match seems quite a bit faster: https://jsperf.com/sort-numer-replace-match

Comment: Thanks @MarkMeyer for your answer.

Comment: Creating an array only to get the first index is quite ugly along with the memory needed to allocate that array.

Answer (score 0):

You can also extract characters using `filter` and `isNaN` and then use `parseInt` to get their integer value to use for your sorting function.

```js
const str = "are1 Ho2w y3ou";

const ordered = str.split(" ").sort((a, b) => {
  let numA = parseInt([...a].filter(c => !isNaN(c)).join(''));
      numB = parseInt([...b].filter(c => !isNaN(c)).join(''));
  return numA - numB;
}).join(' ');

console.log(ordered);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regexp `/\s+/` for splitting the array, that way you can match the tab too.  And the regexp `[^\d+]/g` to remove those chars which are not a number and make the comparison with numbers only.

```js
let str = "Ho2w are1 y3ou"

let sorted = str.split(/\s+/)
  .sort((a, b) => a.replace(/[^\d+]/g, '') - b.replace(/[^\d+]/g, '')).join(' ');

console.log(sorted);
```